# Selecting Rows in Listview and Setting up OnClickListener - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, layout, onclick

I have an app reading from an `SQLite` database using an `Adapter` to display the results in a `RelativeLayout` (code shown below).

I have two problems :

1) The rows in the list are no longer selectable. Before I added in the image (I think) they could be *highlighted / selected*.

*EDIT* - This seems to be caused by the white background I have added to the row ? Does anyone know how I can correct this ?

2) Once the above is fixed, how do I setup an `OnClickListener` to detect when someone selects an item in the list ?

Here is the code for the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="70dip"
     android:background="@drawable/white"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:padding="10sp">

     <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/Logo"
         android:layout_width="50dip"
         android:layout_height="50dip"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_marginRight="6dip" />    

    <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/name"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#FF000000"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:textSize="12sp"
         android:typeface="sans"  
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Logo" />

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/description"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="12sp"
         android:layout_below="@id/name"
         android:textColor="#0000CC"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Logo" />

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/address"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:textSize="12sp"
         android:layout_below="@id/description"
         android:textColor="#990000"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Logo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as to set the on click listener to an item in list view , see the following link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)